# How about getting webpack to ignore some syntactic sugar

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

For example: optional chaining

My application is for internal use, and it's explicitly using the new Chrome browser, so a lot of syntactic sugar doesn't need to be compiled and can be used directly. Compiling only increases the size of the packaged application

Currently I only want to add react and ts plugins, but the package reports that optional chaining is not supported and requires an additional loader

[image]

Comment: How about changing the webpack `target` to a newer version such as es2020?

Comment: @cSharp Thanks for you comment. But the target is 'electron-renderer'， not bundle for browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [documentation page for `target`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#target), it is said:

`electron[[X].Y]-renderer`

> A version of node or electron may be optionally specified. This is denoted by the [[X].Y] in the table above.

Maybe finding the lowest specific version of `electron-renderer` you need to use and targeting that version will help natively supporting some of the syntactic sugar you are using.

Comment: The webpack version is 4 in my project. This version not support. So I must upgrade the version. A lot of works to do...